# .Net Serialization Exception error

Tags: asp.net, .net, serialization

I have a .net application running with no issues on IIS6. I am trying to make the same application work on Win 2008 R2, IIS 7 and running into following error:

The description for Event ID 1334 from source ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: DefaultDomain

Process ID: 3988

Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Type 'my exception.Shared.Exceptions.DataAcquisitionException' in Assembly 'my exception.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeObject(Object obj, MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Serialize(Object o)
   at System.AppDomain.MarshalObject(Object o)

DETAILS TAB:

- Provider

  [ Name]  ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
- EventID 1334

  [ Qualifiers]  49152

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Keywords 0x80000000000000
- TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2014-03-06T17:10:07.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 3324

  Channel Application

  Computer MY SERVER

  Security

  - EventData

  An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated. Application ID: DefaultDomain Process ID: 3988 Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Message: Type 'my exception.Shared.Exceptions.myException' in Assembly 'my exception.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable. StackTrace: at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeObject(Object obj, MemoryStream stm) at System.AppDomain.Serialize(Object o) at System.AppDomain.MarshalObject(Object o)

Any clues into fixing this would be much appreciated!!

Comment: i don't see any java... nor c#...

Comment: Have you added the [<Serializable()> attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the appropriate class?

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: @user3389389 Did you look at the VB example in the link I gave?

Comment: Thanks for your reply everyone. Andrew, I don't know what class this attribute should be added to. The code runs fine on Win 2003 - IIS6, the only change is that its now running on Win 2008, IIS7. So I am not sure if the fix needs to be in the code? Could there be any environmental related issues?

Answer (score 0):

Could be an environmental issue. Do you have same updates of .NET 2.0 applied on win 2003 and win 2008? Do you have any higher framework on win 2003?

Also, I found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941386). The class that caused the exception is different but maybe it will help you or point you in right direction. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same updates on win 2003 and 2008. Not getting anywhere with this.